# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Manjaro

Tags: docker, manjaro

everyone!

i installed docker, docker-compose, then executed next commands:

```
`
sudo systemctl start docker.service
sudo systemctl status docker.service
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
docker run hello-world`
```

OS: Manjaro, Archlinux

error: Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:. Is the docker daemon running?

ALREADY TRY A LOT!! Daemon won't start!

Answer (score 2):

Try `export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock`, then run `docker run hello-world` again.

Comment: Thanks bro, I tried a lot of things and always I was writting `sudo`. Now works good!